# Is it possible to make a list of all the sk_buff's that are currently <LIVE> in the system?

Tags: c, linux, networking

I intend to develop a application that monitors the traffic on particular ports. For this I need to list all the sk_buff data of all the LIVE sk_buff's in the system. How to do this ?

I have written the following code (basically a kernel module.)

```
include <linux/module.h>    /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include </usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic/include/linux/skbuff.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    struct sk_buff *skb;


    printk(KERN_INFO "SKB 1.\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Done 1.\n");
}
```

But I dont know how I *catch* the sk)buff's. I have simply declared a sk_buff instance .. thats all .. 
Please help me to actually catch them live Sk_buff's in the system.

### EDIT

I have tried all the top google search results. They give a very good description of the sk_buff itself, but none of them actually show how to do what I am particularly interested in.

Comment: That `#include </usr/src/..>` smells like a horrible bug waiting to creep up on you. Just use `#include <linux/skbuff.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standardized way. Newly created skbs are not put into any list by default that you could read (that is, when they come fresh out of `skb_alloc`), therefore, there is no way to know all skbs are active from a random code point in the kernel, such as your module. You have at least two options though (both entail modifying core kernel code):

1. Since all skbuffs are allocated from a kmem_cache pool, you could augment the kmem_cache functionality by some function that tells you about all allocated objects.
2. Within the __alloc_skb function, add all newly allocated skbs into a data structure of your liking (and don't forget to remove them again when the skb is freed). This is going to be a major bottleneck, but that's what you have to pay.

As usual, the question: why?

Comment: so that i can make a list of all traffic hitting particular ports

Comment: @Scrooge - netfliter or pcap seem like a more obvious way of going about it then

Comment: @awoodland just cos i am running out of patience to check it out myself .. Its possible to get a list of all packets in netfilter unlike sk_buff's as pointed out by this answer ? could you paste a few links please.

Comment: @scrooge with both [netfilter](http://netfilter.org) and [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) you can get access to every packet that comes into the system if you want. You can cause them to be dropped or rejected through [netfilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#User-space_libraries) too.